# Rule for pagination in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrape, scrapy

i am using Scrapy, to extract information from [website](http://jobs.placementindia.com/lucknow). This is the spider code (partial):

```
class bsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "bsSpider"
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(bsSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.start_urls = [kwargs.get('start_url')]

    rules = (Rule (LinkExtractor(allow=('.*\?id1=.*',),restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="prevNext next"]',)), callback="parse_items", follow= True),)
```

Based on the above rule, it follows next pages. Now, if user wants to provide another start_url to scrape, how to update the above rule dynamically? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [constructor](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py#L34-L36) of `CrawlSpider`:

```
class CrawlSpider(Spider):

    rules = ()

    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        super(CrawlSpider, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
        self._compile_rules()
```

As you can see, if you change `self.rules` somewhere, you need to call `self._compile_rules()` manually to recompile rules.